# formula to find if the qty lesser than 20% of above the safety stock

Tags: excel-formula

I want to know when the total quantity reach 20% above of the safety stock, will give me alert "yes" of need to replenish stock , or No. what is the appropriate formula to use?

[image]

My current formula is:

`IF(B16-C16<20%,"Y","N")`

But I am not sure why it does not work ?

Comment: What formula did you try with ?

Comment: using IF formula which is  B16-C16<20%,"Y","N"....i am not sure does it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula solves your problem.

```
IF(B16/C16 < 1.2, "Yes", "No")
```

or

```
IF(B16/C16 < 120%, "Yes", "No")
```

Your issue comes from your `B16-C16<20%` formula. In your example with apples, that would be translated to `550-500<0.2`

[Here is the documentation about use of %](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2011/08/02/how-to-do-percentages-in-excel/)